# Need to duplicate records based on condition in SAS MACRO

Tags: sas-macro, proc-sql

I need to create a SAS macro to duplicate records based on  a certain condition. Please check the attachment for current output VS desired output.

[image: Check image here]

The only delimiters used are "," and "&".

I am new to SAS macros and hence would need some help.

Comment: May we see what you have tried so far? Have you made a start?

Comment: Hey, I could not get a start at this.. sorry..

Comment: Well, this is probably too broad for Stack Overflow. One good technique is to show that you have made an attempt at researching the problem. This is helpful since we get a lot of people asking questions and they have done no research at all, and it is good to differentiate yourself from those people. Is the manual for this product online, and can you link to the relevant section?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
data have;
  input id widevar $10.;
  cards;
1 a & b
2 c,d
;
run;

data want;
set have;
length longvar $1;
do i = 1 to countc(widevar,'&,') + 1;
  longvar = strip(scan(widevar,i,'&,'));
  output;
end;
keep id longvar;
run;
```